# Related to Chebychef's inequality

Tags: probability, self-study, expected-value, probability-inequalities

Please help me with this problem.

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable for which $E(X)=\mu$. Prove that $$\Bbb{P}(|X-\mu|\ge t)\le \frac{E[(X-\mu)^4]}{t^4}$$
The only thing I have been able to do is that

$\frac{E[(X-\mu)^4]}{t^4}\ge \frac{Var(X)^2}{t^4}$ and also I have at hand the *Cheychef’s inequality* but I have got stuck here as ${\Bbb{P}(….)}^2\lt \Bbb{P}(….)$

Comment: Please add `[self-study]` tag, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: Please study the inequality in its most basic form. It should be straightforward to extend it afterwards.

Comment: @JohnK I got it.. Thank you. I was thinking of complex things and had overlooked the very basics... So silly of me...

Comment: @JohnK has already answered this question for you in his post responding to your previous question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188755!  If you're unsure how to apply his answer, then please follow the link he provided to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov's_inequality) which answers your question explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Define $Y:= \left|X-\mu\right|/t$. We have to prove that 
$$\mathbb P\left\{Y\geqslant 1\right\}\leqslant \mathbb E\left[Y^4\right].$$
This can be done by integrating the pointwise inequality $$ \mathbf 1\left\{Y\geqslant 1\right\}\leqslant Y^4,$$
where $\mathbf 1$ denotes the indicator function.